# proc sql in SAS run 37 times slower than sql in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, sas, sql-tuning

I have this proc sql step in SAS that takes about 1.7sec to complete, however, if i run this SQL via SQL server or any sql client, it takes only 0.04 sec to complete.

From the sastrace log i found that most of the time are spend on 'Total row fetch seconds', which doesnt really explain what cause the 3600% different between SAS Proc SQL and SQL client.

```
Summary Statistics for ODBC are:
Total row fetch seconds were:                       1.736099
Total SQL execution seconds were:                   0.000698
Total SQL prepare seconds were:                     0.000168
Total SQL describe seconds were:                    0.003049
Total seconds used by the ODBC ACCESS engine were     1.743318
```

What exactly is the 'Total row fetch seconds' and how can i improve the run time?

```
proc sql noprint;
    create table work.out1 as
    select a.search_key,
            a.field1,
            c.field2
    from db.tabl_1 as a
            join
                    db.tabl_2 as b
                    on a.search_key = b.search_key
                    and a.search_key in (&search_key)
            join
                    db.Tabl_3 as c
                    on b.field2 = c.field2
                    and upcase(XXX_field) EQ "XXX";
quit;
```

```
&search_key = 19709, 19710, 19711, 19712, .........
```

Edit: to include
Details log from sastrace

```
MPRINT(macro):   proc sql noprint;
SYMBOLGEN:  Macro variable SUBMISSION_STUDY_RUNS resolves to 
            19709, 19710, 19711, 19712, .........
MPRINT(macro):   create table work.out1 as select a.search_key, a.field1, c.field2 from db.tabl_1 as a join db.tabl_2 as b on 
a.search_key = b.search_key and a.search_key in 
(19709, 19710, 19711, 19712, .........) join db.Tabl_3 as c on b.field2 = c.field2 
and upcase(XXX_field) EQ "XXX";
SQLSRV: AUTOCOMMIT is NO for connection 11
SQLSRV: AUTOCOMMIT turned ON for connection id 11


SQLSRV_10181: Prepared: on connection 11
SELECT * FROM "db"."tabl_1"

SQLSRV: AUTOCOMMIT is NO for connection 12
SQLSRV: AUTOCOMMIT turned ON for connection id 12

SQLSRV_10182: Prepared: on connection 12
SELECT * FROM "db"."tabl_2"

SQLSRV: AUTOCOMMIT is NO for connection 13
SQLSRV: AUTOCOMMIT turned ON for connection id 13

SQLSRV_10183: Prepared: on connection 13
SELECT * FROM "db"."Tabl_3"

SQLSRV: AUTOCOMMIT is NO for connection 14
SQLSRV: AUTOCOMMIT turned ON for connection id 14

SQLSRV_10184: Prepared: on connection 14
 select a."search_key", a."field1", c."field2" from "db"."tabl_1" a inner join "db"."tabl_2" b on a."search_key" = b."search_key" inner join 
"db"."Tabl_3" c on b."field2" = c."field2" where ( a."search_key" in (19709, 19710, 19711, 19712, .........) ) and ({fn 
UCASE(c."XXX_field")} = 'XXX')
```

Query i ran in the SQL client:

```
select a.search_key,
a.field1,
c.field2
from db.tabl_1 as a
join
       db.tabl_2 as b
       on a.search_key = b.search_key
       and a.search_key in (19709, 19710, 19711, 19712, .........)
join
       db.Tabl_3 as c
       on b.field2 = c.field2
       and XXX_field = 'XXX';
```

Comment: What *is* the actual SQL produced, and how are you running that -- just to be sure you're comparing apples to apples? The code in the above is not T-SQL; it'll be preprocessed by SAS to produce an actual query. Notably, T-SQL has no `upcase`, `EQ` or an `in` supporting arbitrary parameterized lists.

Comment: Is `db.tabl_1` an ODBC libname? Consider using ODBC passthrough rather than ODBC libnames if you need more control over the actual statement being run.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Not sure if it helps, but i have included the detail from the sas trace log. I had to make some changes on the table name and field name because of company policy

Comment: @RobertPenridge Yes, that is a ODBC table, it is a physcial table on the SQL server

Comment: Can you also paste your query that you are running directly in the SQL client?

Comment: @RobertPenridge I have updated the post to include the query i ran in SQL client

Comment: There's at least one obvious difference between your query and what SAS sends: you have `XXX_field = 'XXX'` while SAS uses `{fn 
UCASE(c."XXX_field")} = 'XXX'`. The latter expression is not amenable to being satisfied by an index on `XXX_field`. The other difference is the shifting of the clauses of the `JOIN` to the `WHERE` -- this should not result in a different execution plan, but nevertheless might. You should verify the running time/execution plan of the *actual* query submitted by SAS.

Comment: Yes exactly what @JeroenMostert said... the issue could be that the query coming from SAS is wrapping one of the fields in the uppercase function.  If the field is being used by an index when running natively in SQL server, wrapping the field in a function prevents the field from being used.  Try removing the uppercase function and see if there's a performance difference.

Comment: @JeroenMostert so i did some more testing, i am starting to think it is cause by the create table statement where a physical table will be created on the SQL server, but on SAS, it seems like it is trying to copy all the data to the SAS server then create the work table, hence the 'Total row fetch'. I would like to hear your thought on this, and if there is a work around. it seems like doesnt matter if i run proc sql or data step it will face the same issue.

Comment: @RobertPenridge stackoverflow only allow me to tag one user per reply, but i would love to hear your thought on the comment above as well.

Comment: I'm not intimately familiar with how SAS works and from the traces alone it's hard to say what exactly it's doing (the `SELECT *` could be for metadata only), but certainly, if it chooses to copy all the source tables first (which seems absurd, but enterprisey software has been known to do worse than that) then certainly that would have a huge impact, especially if it copies it to tables that have no indexes. If you set up a profiler trace on the SQL Server end you would be able to see this (the `SELECT *` would take a long time and have a large row count).

Comment: @user3646699 How many rows are being returned by the query? And how wide is each row?  SAS will definitely return the entirety of the select statement where many clients will limit the #rows returned by a query.  This could easily explain the additional time.

Comment: @RobertPenridge 119 rows, 3 columns. the columns size are just int with 16 length

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like when SAS run proc sql, especially join, it will copy the whole table into SAS memory before doing the join/processing. The same query on SQL server would just join and return the rows that fit the join.

I have replaced all the query with SAS Data step, and the performance is now closer to what i get on the SQL server.

Please let me know if anyone have another work around/explanation

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit long for a comment.

You are comparing two different things -- two completely different databases.  Presumably, they are running on different hardware and in different environments.  The first assumption is that the data is also different.

Second, if you want to understand performance, then you need to learn about `explain`.  Unfortunately, this is not a *supported* feature of `proc sql` (although it is available.

Given the limited information, I would guess that the tables in SQL Server have appropriate indexes built on them, but that the tables in SAS do not.  You can probably add the appropriate indexes and get closer performance numbers for the two systems.  However, that is just speculation.

Comment: since the db.tbl_1, db.tbl_2, and db.tbl_3 are physical table in the SQL server. wont they have the same indexes?

Comment: @user3646699 . . . In that case, you need pass-through mode, so the query is executed on the database box rather than in SAS.

Answer (score 2):

Because you used UPCASE() in one query and not in the other you are not actually running the same query.  Remove the UPCASE() function from your SAS code.